# What's the difference between "eldest" and "oldest"?

Tags: meaning, differences, confusables, superlative-degree

When should I use "eldest" and when should I use "oldest"?

Are the differences semantic or regional? (Or both?)

(What got me wondering is the [`removeEldestEntry()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) method in Java's [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) class.)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Indeed, both *eldest* and *oldest* refer to the greatest in age. The crucial difference, however, lies in the fact that *eldest* can only be used for *related* persons, while *oldest* can be used for *any* person, place or thing in a group of related or unrelated elements. Examples:

> - He is the eldest/oldest of the three children.
> - Mine is the <del>eldest</del>/oldest car on the block.
> - John is the eldest (*less common*)/oldest student in my class.
> - She is the eldest (*less common*)/oldest of my nieces.
> - 'Is New York the <del>eldest</del>/oldest city in the US?'
> - He's the eldest (*less common*)/oldest in the brotherhood.

And while *eldest* can be used for any group of related persons, in reality, it is mostly only used in reference to siblings.

---

New Oxford American Dictionary (2nd Edition) definition of *eldest*:

> (of one out of a group of related or otherwise associated people) of the greatest age; oldest

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. So the Usage in the Java class is wrong.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: You're welcome. Well, in strict grammatical terms, the sentence *Remove eldest entry* is incorrect, considering the definition of *eldest*. However, this is propriety language and Java can do whatever they want! In this sense, the command `removeEldestEntry` could be regarded as correct usage. Indeed, while the *entries* are related, they are not human, except, of course, one argues that Java personifies `Entry`, thus rendering it perfectly correct usage! This is not far-fetched in computer science. For instance, there are *parent* nodes and *child* nodes!

Comment: @Jimi: Agreed, but only if this usage of "eldest" actually refers to one child node compared to two or more other child nodes of the same parent; otherwise the reader might be mislead into thinking that it was such a child node &c.

Comment: @Jimi: Does the same hold true when using *elder* and *older* as adjectives? Namely, *elder* for comparing a group of related persons and *older* for all other groups?

Comment: @Cerberus: Definitely. I've not even come across *eldest* used in the context of node children, anyway...but then, I don't know much comp sci. By the way, what's "&c."? "And co./company?"

Comment: @Scott Mitchell: Indeed, the *elder/older* issue crossed my mind while answering this question, and I felt that that would be a whole new interesting question/discussion all by itself! In the first sense, yes, the usage of *elder/older* follows the same pattern as I described in my answer. In another sense, however, *elder* could refer to superiority/rank, as in *elder statesman*. See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elder?show=1&t=1295646840 for more on this. And, of course, there's the noun, *elder*, as you already mentioned below!

Comment: @Jimi Oke: "&c." is "etc." by another name (the "&", after all, being a stylised way of writing the latin "et" :-)

Comment: @psmears: Golly, who would have thought! I now see how it works, though. Thanks for enlightening me! One learns every day.

Comment: @Jimi: I think elder statesman, elderly woman &c are just remnants of past usage; I'd say "elder" is pretty much restricted to siblings in modern English.

Comment: @Psmears: Stylised, or short: it is said to be first used as a ligature in manuscripts. In fact, it is the natural way to write "et" in non-shortened Merovingian minuscle handwriting; I haven't seen much Roman handwriting outside wax tablets, but my guess would be that it was first used in Merovingian times.

Comment: @Cerberus: I would certainly consider using Merovingian minuscule these days to be stylised ;-)

Comment: @Psmears: Now why am I not surprised... on second thought, i.e. Wikipedia, it seems the *et* ligature already existed in some form from the first century AD onwards.

Comment: See also, the person to the dealer's left in a game of cards: "the eldest hand".

Comment: Now this isn’t right at all: *eldest* is a complete (but somewhat archaic or poetic) synonym for *oldest*, just as *elder* is a complete synonym for *elder*.

Answer (score 2):

They are interchangeable; they both mean exactly the same thing. I think there is a general tendency to use *eldest* in relation to people, e.g.

> John is my eldest son.

For some reason,

> John is my oldest son

sounds wrong, almost like he's the son you've had for longest as opposed to him being the son with the greatest age.

Comment: Interesting, in reference to @Jimi Oke's answer above. It would be *useful* if eldest/oldest could be used to make that distinction (oldest in actual age vs. oldest in the relationship given). For example, "Delaware is the oldest state in the Union, but Virginia is the eldest". Hmmm. Maybe not. :)

Comment: @mattdm: Hmmm, interesting. Well, there is such a thing as personification! We often talk of *sister* cities/ *sister* states/ *parent* institutions. One hears phrases like *elder establishment* and the like. At the superlative, though, *eldest* is usually reserved for related persons. Your example, though, is not unfathomable if one considers the states as members (siblings) of the same family (union).

Answer (score -3):

Both are okay.
Just *elder*, *eldest* are often used to replace *older* and *oldest*, nowadays.

Comment: *Elder* and *Older* have some differences, though. *Elder* can be used as a noun, as in "Respect your elders," whereas *older* cannot.

Comment: Also, I don't use "elder" in place of "older" most of the time.

Comment: @ScottMitchell The [OED disagrees](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130967) with you. It gives plenty of citations form the 20th century, and even one from the 21st.

Comment: @tchrist, I can't see the OED entry, I don't have a subscription to the site. Are you saying that "Respect your olders" is a valid sentence?

Comment: @ScottMitchell Yes, of course. Citations: “The olders say that the Creator told them to make their homesteads circular.” [1967]; “The ‘olders’, all volunteers, go through nine days of inservice training. They get one credit for their work with the grade-schoolers.” [1972] “Second graders are olders, kindergartners are youngers, for certain. But where do first graders fit?” [1997] “The Malay feudal system of old when the Sultan's must trusted council of olders were conferred a hereditary title.” [2001] You should be albe to access the OED through your school or public library.

Comment: @ScottMitchell I would myself say *elders* for most of those citations, save maybe contrasting with *youngers*, but I cannot deny the evidence that there are indeed people who use *olders* where I would use *elders*.