# Word for the longest time in spent in a group

Tags: word-choice

A friend and I were discussing what would be an appropriate word to describe the person that has been in a group for the longest. I suggested the word [elder](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elder), but that seems to apply the age of the group member is older than the others. The word we are searching for wouldn't imply that they are older, just that they have been in that group for the longest time. Any suggestions for a good word for this?

Comment: Patriarch (a little formal!) - but elder would be the normal term here, in spite of the other common meaning. An _elder statesman_ isn't necessarily one of the oldest.

Comment: The Senior Member.

Comment: In the UK Parliament the MP with the *longest unbroken record of service* is the [Father of the House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_of_the_House), regardless of chronological age.

Answer (score 3):

Really, a lot depends on the culture of the organization.  While a simply titled ***"senior member"*** might be acceptable in some clubs, other possibilities, again depending on the club, could be ***"veteran member"***, ***"upper classman"***, ***"member emeritus"***, ***"grand poobah"*** (ok, maybe not the last one)

Comment: A member [*emeritus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emeritus) would no longer be a member, though. (The *e-* comes from the Latin for *out*)

Comment: @AndrewLeach, "member emeritus" may be a little out of the OP's scope, but I was thinking of it in terms of this definition (from M-W Online): *"one retired from professional life but permitted to retain as an honorary title the rank of the last office held"* - like a person granted lifetime member status even though they may not be actively contributing to the daily operations of the organization.  Thanks for keeping me honest though! :-)

Comment: Downvoter - any constructive criticism?

Comment: "Senior" is tough when referring to technical teams, because the work is used along with "junior" to denote experience in the field. Situations often arise where a senior programmer is the newest member of the team. I came to this topic to find an alternative. Thanks for including some.

Answer (score 1):

If the member has been around since the group's beginnings, you can use [*founder*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/founder) or [*original member,*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/original) depending on whether you want to emphasize a role in establishing the group.

Otherwise, you can use *(most) senior member,* as John Lawler suggests, or [*oldest member*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113805/oldest-for-age-vs-length-of-time) if you don't mind a little ambiguity. [*Eldest*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eldest) can also imply seniority, but it's more often used to specify the age of a family member, so you're right to avoid it.

Comment: In British English, *oldest member* would probably be understood to refer to the member that is oldest (eldest) in age. I would say *longest standing member*.

Comment: I can see people having the same ambiguity problem with _senior_ in American English. _Longest standing_ is a good suggestion – you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Tenure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tenure?s=t) refers to the length of a person's term in a given position. So, calling a group member **longest-tenured** would refer to their time in the group and nothing more.

See, for example, this usage referring to a coach's length of time with a current team:

> On Thursday, Charlie Manuel managed his 1,332d game with the Phillies, making him **the franchise's longest-tenured manager**.

Comment: In Britain, I don't think we would use ***longest-tenured*** as an adjective, and, although we would understand, ***member with the longest tenure***, I don't think we would use it in that manner. That term would normally be used to refer to a person having held a particular *position or office* for the longest period - and may continue to be used even after the person in question no longer holds that particular position, and indeed even after they have died until a successor holds the position for a longer period.

Answer (score 1):

I think a common term for this in Britain would be ***longest standing member***.

***Oldest*** would normally refer to the oldest (eldest) in age.
***The Senior member*** would (if used at all), I think, be understood as referring to authority rather than tenure or age.
***A senior member*** is most likely to be understood as referring to one of a group of members over a certain age (typically 60 or 65), who may pay reduced subscriptions.

I don't think we would use ***longest-tenured*** as an adjective, and, although we would understand, ***member with the longest tenure***, I don't think we would use it in that manner. (See also my comments under the answer with that suggestion.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the make-up of the group, you could use ***Founder***.  E.g. if the group still has the first member in it, this would be the word to use and it would describe what you want.  Otherwise, ***longest-serving*** is fairly common when talking about group members, although it is not a singular word.

Comment: That only means the person was with the group when it started. They could have quit a couple weeks later, and the term would still apply.

Comment: Exactly, hence "depending on the make-up of the group". The term would still apply to that person if they left the group, but because they would no longer be in the group, so the context would be different.

Comment: I think longest-serving is the best answer in this thread, though it dislike it because it's clunky.

Answer (score -1):

The term I tend to hear used for something similar to this is "lifer". This is generally applied when a person was with a group as long as it is possible to be. For example, my church recently gave "lifer" awards to graduating seniors who were members since the infant nursery, and my son's High School put a special mark in the graduation program for "lifers" who attended school in that same district since kindergarten.

Here's an example I found in a [recent news story](http://newsok.com/oklahoma-tornadoes-the-big-dog-the-little-boy-and-the-hug-that-triumphs-over-tragedy/article/3833468):

> Jim Routon's idea of displacement is moving on the other side
>   Pennsylvania Avenue. He's a Southside lifer in OKC, except for years
>   spent at what then was Central State University in Edmond.

Of course the term is also used for criminals serving "life" sentences.

Comment: Surely your term *lifer* applies only if the member has been there effectively 'for life'. That's not what the question asked: in the OP's question, the person could have joined the group at any age but still be the person who has been in that group for longer than any other current member. [In your answer, you mention *graduating seniors*, which I assume refers to people in their upper teens(?). If so, how can they be *lifers* if they still have most of their lives yet to live, and may/could leave the group in the near future?]

Comment: @TrevorD - I'm just relating how I've heard the term used. If you don't think that makes sense, I'm afraid I can't help you.